# Dynamically adding a textbox to a databound checkboxlist in c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've got a .net web app, c# backend, sql server data layer. I have an asp:checkboxlist which I am populating from a stored procedure via direct data binding:

**ASP.net**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblMyPlans" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**C#**

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConn"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectMyPlans", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
conn.Open();

using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (dr.Read()) {
        cblMyPlans.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["Name"].ToString(), dr["PlanID"].ToString()));

    }
}
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

Im not sure if its even possible, but based on a certain flag that comes out of that `SqlDataReader`, I need to dynamically add a small `textbox` to each item of the cbl that satisifies that flag.

How can I add the `asp:TextBox` dynamically during the `databind`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically add your CheckBoxList with "manual" elements.

This code will create same html as the CheckBoxList but you can add additional elements per your requirements...

Code behind:

```
public void FillPH()
    {
        var MyList = new List<ListItem>
        {
            new ListItem("One", "1"),
            new ListItem("Two", "2"),
            new ListItem("Three", "3")
        };

        Table myTable = new Table();

        foreach (var item in MyList)
        {
            //Create new checkbox
            CheckBox CB = new CheckBox();
            CB.Text = item.Text;
            CB.ID = item.Value;

            //Create tablr row and td, then adds them accordignly
            TableRow TR = new TableRow();
            TableCell TD = new TableCell();
            TD.Controls.Add(CB);
            TR.Controls.Add(TD);

            //IF <YOUR FLAG GOES HERE>-->
            if (item.Value == "2")
            {
                //Create your input element and place it in a new Table cell (TD2)
                TextBox TB = new TextBox();
                TB.ID = string.Format("tb_{0}", item.Value);
                TableCell TD2 = new TableCell();
                TD2.Controls.Add(TB);
                TR.Controls.Add(TD2);
            }

            myTable.Controls.Add(TR);
        }

        fillMe.Controls.Add(myTable);
    }
```

Front:

```
 <div>
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="fillMe" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
 </div>
```

Comment: Simple and easier than the way I was trying to do it. This worked.

Comment: if you don't care about the same HTML structure as the CheckList, you can do this much simpler (just adding CheckBox directly to the placeholder and your input if needed)

Comment: how to cast the table to a checkboxlist?